# Why jQuery Image Slider does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I had just watched a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkzVFB3Ba_o) about Building a Jquery Image gallery (since I have little knowledge of Jquery), However it does not seem to work by any means. I went through my code thoroughly cross checking it, and fixed all possible errors but it still does'nt work. What is it that I'm doing wrong??

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide"><img src="images/1.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="images/2.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="images/3.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="images/4.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="images/5.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="images/6.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider
{
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slider.slides
{
    display: block;
    width: 6000px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#slider.slide
{
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Jquery/Javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

    var $slider=$('#slider');
    var $slideContainer=$slider.find('.slides')
    var $slides=$slideContainer.find('.slide');
    var width=720;
    var animationSpeed=1000;
    var pause = 3000;
    var CurrentSlide=1;
    var interval;

     function startSlider()
     {


        interval= setInterval(function(){
            $slider.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width},animationSpeed,function()
                CurrentSlide++;
                if (CurrentSlide===$slides.length){
                    CurrentSlide=1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left',0); 
                }
                });
        },pause);
    }

    function pauseSlider()
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

       $slider.on('mouseenter',pauseSlider).on('mouseleave',startSlider);
       startSlider();

    });



</script>
```

Source folder of my project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M3kvUAWlCRqiZIWLLmTH_60qo0gsxzgT

Comment: What's not working? Please be specific.

Comment: The overall slider is not working at all, the pics are not positioned in the slider and so on and so forth, It's almost like the slider does'nt exist. I'm attaching my source code folder as a reference in the edit section Please wait

Comment: Try adding it to a codepen

Comment: You've any browser console errors?

Comment: You've a syntax error in your project. You are missing a `{` in `animationSpeed, function() ` after `$slider.animate({`.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes I have a syntax error which says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", although the identifier on Line 88 (CurrentSlide) is declared above, as you can see

Comment: I've pointed out the error. Please correct it. :)

Comment: Yes I corrected it, but it still does'nt have any effect on my final output :(

Comment: I do not see any references to an actual start of the slider. Is that simply left out? 

Call your method `startSlider()` on document load for instance.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing

```
<ul class="slides">
```

Comment: I have added it now,however it still does not have any effect on the final product

Comment: #slider.slide css space missing it should be like:  #slider .slide

Answer (score 0):

you are missing curly brackets after function

```
  $slider.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width},animationSpeed,function()
```

it should be

```
  $slider.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width},animationSpeed,function(){
```